# GAE Python: Images working on localhost but not working after deploy

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
- url: /static/images/(.*\.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/images/\1
  upload: uploads/(.*\.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

Above is my app.yaml file. It is working on localhost but not working after deploy.  I got 404 response in the gae website.  Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using microsoft as a development environment?

Comment: Why are you uploading `uploads` instead of `static`?

Comment: wait I thought upload is for the path of the image file upload in the website. like the blob image that you created in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to upload files from the wrong folder. Try this instead:

```
- url: /static/images/(.*\.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/images/\1
  upload: static/images/(.*\.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

Comment: Was actually @Wooble answer in the comments :)

Comment: @peterretief True.. but you can't accept a comment as far as I know.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The AppEngine is case sensitive file system, check that the case of the images matachs the file name.

---

Maybe your files are not uploaded, start with a basic handler to see whats preventing the upload:

```
- url: /static/images
  static_files: static/images
  upload: uploads
```

Comment: double checked it, they are all lower case and looked exactly the same.